# how to auto generate html table form in singal click

Tags: php, html

i want generate  following code in dynamic way tr or th may be incrase
i enetr tr & th then get following out put

```
    <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/css/*.js" rel="stylesheet""> </script>


    <link href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/css/*.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <title>   </title>
```

```
   <tr>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>

           <th> </th>
   </tr>
```

i want generate  above code in dynamic way tr or th may be incrase
i enetr tr & th then get following out put

i enetr tr & th then get following out put
i enetr tr & th then get following out put

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
hear the code that solve problem 


<html>
<head>
    
    <title>html table form </title>
</head>
<body><form action="" method="post">
    enter no of tr <input type=text name=tr> <br>
    enter no of th <input type=text name=th> <br>
    <input type=submit name=b1 value="get code">
</body>
</html>

<?php 

    extract($_REQUEST);

    if(isset($b1))
    {
        echo"<pre>";
        echo"&lt;html&gt<br>";
        echo"   &lt;head&gt<br><br>";

        echo'
        &lt;script language="javascript" src="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/css/*.js" rel="stylesheet""&gt; &lt;/script&gt;<br>
    
        &lt;link href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/css/*.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt <br><br>';

        echo"        &lt;title&gt";
        echo"   &lt;/title&gt<br><br>";
        
        echo"   &lt;/head&gt<br>";
        echo"&lt;body&gt<br>";
        $i=0;
        while($i<$tr)
        {
            echo"<br>       &lt;tr&gt;<br>";
            $j=0;
            while($j<$th)
            {
            echo"<br>               &lt;th&gt; &lt;/th&gt;<br>";
            $j++;
            }
            $i++;
            echo"       &lt;/tr&gt;<br>";
        }
        

        echo"   &lt;/body&gt<br>";        
        echo"&lt;/html&gt";

        echo"</pre>";
    }
?>
```